# Netbean for PHP code completion to @var missing?

Tags: php, netbeans, netbeans-7, var, code-completion

I have the following code:

```
/** @var ObjectClass $instanceName  */
$x = $instanceName->method();
```

and not get code completion while typing `$instanceName->`, Netbean have such feature? I'm missing some config or using a wrong syntax? `$instanceName` was obtained from a service selector, so no parameter type hint neither property type hint, just remain this option, but is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Should be this:

```
/* @var $instanceName ObjectClass */
```

**If the ObjectClass is inside a namespace, you must declare the namespace... PHP usings are not included.**

for example:

```
/* @var $instanceName \Namespace\LikeA\Boss\ObjectClass */
```